# AWS terraform, I am getting error while trying to apply the code, kildy help and let e know where I am going wrong

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

```
    terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.0.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
  access_key = ""
  secret_key = ""
}

variable "ami" {
  type    = string
  default = "ami-026ebd4cfe2c043b2"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "prod-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "prod-gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "prod-subnet-A" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

}

resource "aws_route_table" "prod-rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.prod-gw.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "prod-rt-assoc" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.prod-subnet-A.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.prod-rt.id
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2" {
  ami               = var.ami
  instance_type     = "t2.micro"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  subnet_id         = aws_subnet.prod-subnet-A.id
  tags = {
    Name = "prod-server"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "prod-ebs" {
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  size              = 20
  type              = "gp2"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "prod-ebs-atach" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.prod-ebs.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.my-ec2.id
}


resource "aws_security_group" "prod-sg" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }

}

resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = aws_security_group.prod-sg.id
  network_interface_id = aws_instance.my-ec2.primary_network_interface_id
}
```

---

creating Route in Route Table (rtb-0f67c55aacc146f4f) with destination (10.0.0.0/16): InvalidParameterValue: The destination CIDR block 10.0.0.0/16 is equal to or more specific than one of this VPC's CIDR blocks. This route can target only an interface or an instance.
│       status code: 400, request id: 8924d2dc-ff6b-4a9d-9467-9711672e4e06

Comment: What is your goal here? Why would you want to redirect `10.0.0.0/16` to the internet gateway? Normally you want to redirect anything *but* `10.0.0.0/16` there / aka `0.0.0.0/0`.

Answer (score 0):

Iternet traffic is denoted as `0.0.0.0/0` in CDIR. So it should be:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "prod-rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.prod-gw.id
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin, I am able to create the infrastructure, now. Got confused with the routing of CIDR.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create the key pair and attach to the same instance?

Comment: @SubhajitDas This is a new issue, not related to the question you made. I would suggest new SO question for the new problem.

Comment: @SubhajitDas How did it go? Is is still unclear how you should your issue with `CIDR`?

Comment: Hi Marcin, Aplogy for the late reply, yes I am able to get it now, as I am able to create te infratsructure and came to know where I was going wrong.

Comment: @SubhajitDas Ah oh. Since you haven't accepted the answer as helpful. it was unclear if you solved your issue.